# Get data from wp7 Listbox in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

New to C# so I’m confused. I have this kind scenario:

```
   private void result_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 

                   var data = from query in Event.Descendants("event") 
                   select new EventManager 
                   { 
                       name = (string)query.Element("name"), 
                       place = (string)query.Element("place"), 
                       date = (DateTime)query.Element("date"), 
                       time = (DateTime)query.Element("time") 
                   }; 

        myListBox.ItemsSource = data; 
   }
```

1. If I want to save data in an array/container?
2. If I want to retrieve data from the ListBox later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set and later on get ItemsSource like this

```
List<String> container = new List<String>();
listBox.ItemsSource = container;
List<String> retrieve = (List<String>) listBox.ItemsSource;
```

Just like List you can have any container you want